# smooth interpolation of two points, with an angle as a parameter

Tags: python, math, interpolation, maya, spline

in Autodesk Maya when an user creates an animation of two keyframes the program displays the animation curve like in the pictures below. There's a curve with a start and an end point, spline interpolated, the user can edit the angle on both ends to edit it like this.

[spline interpolated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbNxu.png)

[angle edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3WL9.png)

In math, I've found how to interpolate via several methods between two points, but I haven't found how to get the shape of  a curve like in the second picture, and with an angle on both points as a parameter to edit.

Comment: Both images are the same, is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be some kind of cubic parametric curve.

Curve might be represented as [Hermite spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) or in [Bezier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) form - the most widely used form in computer graphics.

Bezier curve description requires end points and control points that define direction (angle) and magnitude of derivatives at the ends.